# Nx Storybook (Webpack 5) "exports is not defined" and infinite loading

Tags: webpack, storybook, nrwl-nx

I have upgraded Nx packages to latest version 14.7.5 and it broke my Storybook build which was still using Webpack 4. So I figured updating it to Webpack 5 might fix the problem and after the migration it is successfully building, but the Storybook gets stuck on the main page and infinitely shows the loading animation (XHR call `/progress` never returns) and in console there is `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` error. This error comes from one of my generated files that is in JS (rest of the files is in TypeScript). I am not sure if the error is causing the infinite loading but it is my only clue.

When I build the Storybook statically it also shows this warning during the compilation:

```
 export 'AssetService' (reexported as 'AssetService') was not found in './protos/Asset_pb_service' (module has no exports)
```

which comes from the same file as the error in the console so it might be connected (the files has exports though).

My main Storybook configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  typescript: { reactDocgen: false },
  stories: [],
  addons: [
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-essentials',
      options: {
        backgrounds: true,
        viewport: false,
      },
    },
    '@nrwl/react/plugins/storybook',
    'storybook-dark-mode'
  ],
};
```

Storybook configuration of the main app:

```
// This loads the configuration above
const rootMain = require('../../../.storybook/main');

module.exports = {
  ...rootMain,

  core: { ...rootMain.core, builder: 'webpack5' },

  stories: [
    ...rootMain.stories,
    '../src/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../*.stories.mdx',
    '../../../libs/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../../../libs/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // apply any global webpack configs that might have been specified in .storybook/main.js
    if (rootMain.webpackFinal) {
      config = await rootMain.webpackFinal(config, { configType });
    }

    // add your own webpack tweaks if needed

    return config;
  },
};
```

Storybook package versions:

```
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.5.12",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.5.12",
    "@storybook/core-server": "6.5.12",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.12",
    "@storybook/react": "6.5.12",
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was most likely caused by the library `ts-protoc-gen` which is generating the JS files that caused the error and seems to be connected with this [issue](https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen/issues/111). We have finally resolved this issue by removing `.babelrc` file from the library with the generated files, which somehow solved the compilation of said JS files when they were indirectly imported.

Comment: I am also experiencing this, what did you actually do to solve this?

Comment: I did not actually solve the error `exports is not defined`, I was just able to move it from preview.js to the individual stories. So now most of the stories work, just the ones that have this error are not working, instead of the whole storybook not working.

Comment: What is in your babelrc? I removed `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` and things started to work for me.

Comment: I am using the default Nx babel configuration and there is no mention of `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` but it could be used inside the plugins. Thanks for the tip.